# Trigger jquery event for ie8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

I would like to trigger a javascript event for ie8 or lower versions. This is my markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie10 lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie10 lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie10 lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie10"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 9]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
...
</html>
```

And jquery:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("html.lt-ie9").load(function(){
        alert('ie8 only');
    });
});
```

But this is doing nothing at all in any browser.

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: What version of jquery are you using? 2.x dropped support for IE

Comment: Good idea but I'm using 1.11 so it isn't that.

Comment: `$("html.lt-ie8").on('load', function(){ alert('ie8 only');});` Try using on instead.

Comment: But it turns out load() is deprecated in 1.8. Will edit the question

Comment: Hmm actually using on as per your example above doesn't load. I wonder if this is because as per the jquery docs for 'on': "In all browsers, the load, scroll, and error events (e.g., on an <img> element) do not bubble"

Comment: @Brighty Ya, onload event doesn't bubble, should be bound here to window object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On document ready you could just check if the html element has that certain IE class and then do something:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    if ($('html').hasClass('lt-ie9')) {
      alert('ie8 only');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You might not want to do this, like this. But it should work.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   if($('html').hasClass('lt-ie9')) {
      // later than IE9 only...
   }
});
```

I would recommend that you used feature detection  instead of browser detection  .